# Gradle: how do I configure the jar location to be in the parent directory of the project?

Tags: build, jar, directory, gradle

I'm trying to build a Gradle JAR project that is a subproject of another and would like the output JAR file to be in a parent directory (to be specific in the "lib" directory of the parent, or sibling). How do I configure Gradle for this and where is this documented?

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Each project has its own build output directory, and I don't recommend to deviate from that. It's confusing and means you will no longer be able to clean projects independently.

Comment: Hi Peter - I understand the principle of segregating subproject builds, but in this case I'm creating a Grails plugin that depends on a jar that is in a subproject (containing groovy sources), which is built using Gradle. I want jar to be output to the plugin's "lib" dir. The plugin itself doesn't have a build (since it's a Grails plugin), only the subproject.

Comment: Hopefully Gradle is flexible enough to do what I want to do without imposing strict rules about project structure, like Maven ;)

Comment: Sure, but there are likely better solutions to your problem (which I don't know enough about).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In `build.gradle`, add:

```
libsDirName = '../../lib'
```

The config settings are shown in the official Gradle docs for the [java plugin](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/java_plugin.html).

BTW, I fully agree with the intent behind the comments and answers given by Peter and Hiery, but sometimes the simplest solution is the best one.

Answer (score 8):

Agreed with the comment Peter typed. However I think you want to express that the parent project depends on the output of the submodule. Expressing that and ensuring that the parent copies the output of the submodule to its 'lib' directory makes more sense.

```
task assembleSubModules(type: Copy) {
  destinationDir = file("lib")

  into("lib") {
    project.subprojects.each { p ->
      from(p.tasks.withType(Jar)*.outputs)
    }
  }
}
```