# Gradle: how to configure which directory JARs go to

Tags: gradle, gradle-plugin

I'm using the Gradle distribution plugin, so I have something like:

`apply plugin: 'distribution'`

The JARs end up in `/lib` in the TAR or ZIP file, but I want to put them somewhere else, such as `share/lib` or something.

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18583896/gradle-how-do-i-configure-the-jar-location-to-be-in-the-parent-directory-of-the

Comment: that sounds like a bad idea... have you considered publishing your artifacts to a repository? eg nexus or artifactory?